# Changing Type's Namespace During Binary Serialization Before .NET 4

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, binary

Doing this is .NET 4.0 and newer is trivial using the BindToName method, which is the opposite of the BindToType method of the SerializationBinder.  But, does anyone know a way to do this in **.NET 3.5**?

[Note: The .NET 4.0 answer to this is here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4628469/maintain-net-serialized-data-compatability-when-moving-classes/4629942)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use something which implements the [ISerializationSurrogate interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.iserializationsurrogate%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) to do this,and its quite a lot of work.

Check out this [MSDN article by Jeffrey Richter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188950.aspx) from back in 2002.

It's unfortunately all fantastically fiddly.

Comment: I was afraid of that and never could figure out using Surrogates just to map to an old namespace. Going to leave this open for a while to see if anyone knows of an example.